# PUSH x VS MOV [ESP], x?

Tags: x86, ghidra

I am a beginner in RE. I compiled some code (x86 32bit), and opened it up in Ghidra.
I come across the following instruction right before a call:

**MOV dword ptr [ESP], 0x3c**

Where 0x3c is the offset to the start of a string in .rdata, so this acts as a parameter to the proceeding function call which takes a char* data type as an argument.

The question is, why does the compiler decide to do this instead of a simple PUSH 0x3c?

Thanks!

Comment: Compiled with GCC?

Comment: Hey check this useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766534/cost-of-push-vs-mov-stack-vs-near-memory-and-the-overhead-of-function-calls